# tableview and external data sources

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, delegates, xcode8

I have a view controller with a UITable View.

My data source is external. I have use data task to go to some URL with certain parameters, get back a JSON response, and I end up with a Swift dictionary object that contains the data that I wish to add to the table view cells. All this happens in the viewdidload function.

How would I go and populate my table with data from my dictionary as this needs to happen only after I have received my data?

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
    cell.myLabel.text = json_surveys[indexPath.row]["SName"]
    return (cell)

}
```

So how can I tell tableView about my dictionary but only after I actually have the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to reload your data from inside the completion of your data task you will want to dispatch the call to the main thread like this

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: when i add the line i get the following error: Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'

Comment: do you have a reference to your table view through an IBOutlet or programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Use `self.tableView.reloadData()` whenever you have received your data from the server. This will reload all the cells of your `tableView`.

Comment: when i add the line i get the following error: Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'

Answer (score -2):

You need to have your `tableView` delegate and datasource assigned to this `UIViewController`.

You can do it as such:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
....
```

Then you need to add the `cellForRow` and `numberOfRows` protocol functions in this class.

I see you are already adding `cellForRow`, you should also add `numberOfRows` function that's why you're getting the error.

Add like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataArray.count
}
```

Then you can call `tableView.reloadData()` whenever you're finished fetching data from the server and add it in an array e.g. dataArray.